# How can i catch number or chars using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to catch or filter a number from string example:

```
var Mystring = "4.0" // or sometimes 4.5
```

In this example, I need to find the `.5` or `.0` to replace it or remove it.

Comment: What is your intended output?  `Math.floor(parseFloat(Mystring, 10))` will round it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to truncate the number?

```
Math.floor(Number("4.0"))
```

It works even if there are spaces:

```
Math.floor(Number("    4.5   "))
```

Comment: will from one query i get like response ratehotel as 4.5 or 4.0 .. what i whant is to delete .0 or .5 from this response, like this i can add image stars. thank you to replay

Comment: @user1447313: You can also use indexOf to find the decimal point `.` and use `substr` to get only the part before decimal point `.`. Or you can just use my method above and put it inside `String()` to create a string without the part after decimal point.